# Getting the *complete* SQL query generated by Entity Framework when specifying a variable at runtime?

Tags: entity-framework

I know that I can simply use `ToString()` to see the SQL statement generated by EF. But how can I get the SQL when I am using a variable in my statement? In the following `aType` and `bVal` are each variables.

```
var foo = context.PUBooleanAttributes
                 .Where(u => u.PUAttributeID == aType && u.Value == bVal)
                 .Select(abc => abc.User);
```

which generates the following:

```
{SELECT 
    [Extent2].[UserID] AS [UserID], 
    [Extent2].[Email] AS [Email], 
    [Extent2].[GUID] AS [GUID]
    FROM  [dbo].[PUBooleanAttributes] AS [Extent1]
    INNER JOIN [dbo].[Users] AS [Extent2] ON [Extent1].[UserID] = [Extent2].[UserID]
    WHERE ([Extent1].[PUAttributeID] = @p__linq__0) AND ([Extent1].[Value] = @p__linq__1)}
```

What I'd like to see is the actual values supplied at runtime instead of `@p__linq__0`

Comment: The statement you have **IS** what is sent to SQL Server - even at runtime, there are **no** substitutions made - the statement is sent to SQL Server **with parameters** in place .

Comment: Is there a way of getting the parameters so I can cut n paste and execute?